# Trying to scrape image link put selector isn't working

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy

Sorry if this question is elementary, but I'm working on a small beginner project and I am in need of support and don't know where else to look.

I'm trying to scrape the image link text (src), but I just can't get the selector right. An example of the css of the site is below.

```css
<img class="s-item__image-img selectorgadget_selected" alt="Nintendo Switch (Red &amp; Blue Joy-Con) &amp; accessories!  6 Month Warranty!" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/n8QAAOSwdepfKFw0/s-l225.webp"
```

I've tried something like this,, and it doesn't break the code, but nothing is grabbed:

```css
product_image = product.css(
'.s-image__image-img::attr(src)').extract_first()
```

I have other selectors, but the alt in the middle is messing it up unlike the others. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `attr(src)').extract_first()` -> `attr(src)).extract_first()`. Remove the extra single quote.

Comment: But the single quote is to go with the one at the beginning. The program doesn't run without it.

Answer (score 0):

Typo. `.s-image` should be `.s-item`.

```py
product_image = product.css('.s-item__image-img::attr(src)').get()
```

WARNING: Don't ever use methods `.extract_first()` and `.extract()`. The behavior of `.extract()` is inconsistent. Switch to `.get()`, `.getall()`.

Comment: That was it. The solution was even stupider than I thought. Thanks!